# Mongodb (or mongoose) get documents with a current date less than its own interval

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Document structure (fields unrelated to this question removed):

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    lastDate: Date,
    interval: Integer, // in seconds
    mode: String
}
```

What I'm looking for is a query similar to:

```
{
    lastDate: {
        $lt: new Date() - $interval
    },
    mode: {
        $in: ['collect', 'debug']
    }
}
```

Therefore the query would get all documents with a `lastDate` that's less than the current date/time minus its own interval. Also only get documents with mode set to collect or debug.

Can this be done with a basic query or do I need to use aggregate or mapReduce?

Comment: How can `lastDate` ever be greater than `lastDate + interval`? Can interval be `negative`?

Comment: @BatScream, you're right. My conditions are wrong in my question. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, your condition is

```
lastDate < current_time - interval
```

which is equivalent to

```
lastDate + interval < current_time
```

Therefore, instead of (or in addition to) storing `lastDate` and `interval`, store their sum. The sum can be stored as seconds since epoch or as a date - you can pick what's most convenient for you in your client code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I'm not sure if it's the best one performance-wise.

The query that works:

```
{
    $where: "this.lastDate < new Date() - this.interval",
    mode: {
        $in: ['collect', 'debug']
    }
}
```

Uses [the `$where` operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where):

> Use the `$where` operator to pass either a string containing a JavaScript expression or a full JavaScript function to the query system. The `$where` provides greater flexibility, but requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection. Reference the document in the JavaScript expression or function using either `this` or `obj`.